# Strict Standards: Non-static method lang::utf8decode() should not be called statically in

Tags: php, utf-8, utf, utf8-decode

I have this line

```
$newLang[$key] = (key_exists($key2, $_LANG)) ? 
                 lang::utf8decode($_LANG[$key2], 'UTF-8') : '';
```

In more than one place, it seems it is creating an error for every place it is present.
 Do you know why this is happening and how to solve it?

example:

```
foreach($matches[1] as $key)
{
    $key2 = $template.'_'.md5($key);
    $newLang[$key] = (key_exists($key2, $_LANG)) ? lang::utf8decode($_LANG[$key2], 'UTF-8') : '';
}
$files[$template] = $newLang;
$count += sizeof($newLang);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the error pretty much explains your problem ;)
Je are calling the non-static method lang::utf8decode() staticly, you can not do that.
So change it in your class by adding the static prefix:

```
public static function utf8decode(){}
```

Or don't call it staticly, but do:

```
$lang=new lang();
$lang->utf8decode();
```

Comment: thank, but I still don't know how to change it based on your answer. sorry, I really don't know classes...

Comment: Everywhere where you use lang::utf8decode();, remove that call and change it to $lang=new $lang(); $lang->utf8decode(); It will stop giving the error ;)